# How to select an item from a Table in seleniumWebDriver for Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in QA automation and i am using selenium for this.

I am trying to select a submenu that is open from a table. The option that i want to select is "Nueva Carta Crédito".

The code from the menu is:

```
<div id='lmoptions'  style="border-style: outset;font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 100%;height: 5px;position: absolute;background-color: #88BBD9;" >
<table id='lmoptionstable'>
    <tr onmouseover="parent.highliterow(this)" onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','V', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Vista</label></td></tr>

    <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','I', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Nueva Carta Crédito</label></td></tr>
    <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','CP', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Preaviso Completo</label></td></tr>
    <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','A', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Enmienda</label></td></tr>
    <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','N', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Negociación</label></td></tr>
    <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','U', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Actualización</label></td></tr>
    <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','W', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Bandeja de Trabajo</label></td></tr>


</table>
```

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

When you post a question you should insert your attempts to solve the problem: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

You could do in this way:

```
        WebElement table= driver.findElementById("lmoptionstable");
        WebElement el= table.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr/td/label[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']"));
        el.click();
```

Comment: I made an error. I used "driver" instead of "table". If the html is only this, you are right. Otherwise, is better identify first the table.

Comment: What is the reason for setting the Nueva Carta Crédito to a WebElement?

Comment: Just to readability.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidePatti when i execute, i get this exception org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Cannot click on element

Answer (score 1):

If the Nueva Carta Crédito option is visible and all you want to do is click it, simply use this function:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']").Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element you want to click is visible,

```
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']").Click();
```

If the element you want to click is visible only after mouse over/hover,

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement elementToHover = driver.findElement(By.id("lmoptionstable"));
    WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']"));
    action.moveToElement(elementToHover).click(elementToClick).build().perform();
```